# How can i fit the logistic regression model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I try to fit the logistic regression model but its shows error.

Code:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Error:

```
This solver needs samples of at least 2 classes in the data, but the data contains 
only one class: 0
```

Comment: The error message says that `y_train` is all zeros; there's nothing to learn there.

Comment: The error is self-explainable; did you check your data before rushing to open a question here?

Comment: @GoldenLion balanced data or not seems to have nothing to do here; the error says that there are *no* samples with class other than `0`.

Comment: df['target'].value_counts() will help explore if the class output only has one value

Answer (score 1):

First things first, this is a basic question and you can find your answer anywhere if you'd copy-paste your error. Get used to making a search first before asking here, cause users are highly against blind questions.

And for your answer, I think you may rush a bit to create your model. Have you checked the value counts of your target variable?

Let's assume your data saved as df. To check;

```
df['target'].value_counts()
```

This will return the number of classes and their counts in the dataset. Simply -as in your case - if there is only 1 class, there is nothing to predict. Printing the class name would be a better approach rather than building a model.